# Display Hyperlink If Applicable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

I need a way to display a hyperlink if it exists in a string. So for the example below I need `https://thegameawards.com/awards/` to show up as a clickable link, how would I go about this in JavaScript?

`VOTE HERE: https://thegameawards.com/awards/`

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more: "display a hyperlink if it exists in a string"

Comment: Lets say you have a string `this is not a link but this is https://randomlink.com`, I want the `https://randomlink.com` to show as a clickable link instead of a word that can't be clicked on.

Comment: You should try something and ask a specific question mentioning what went wrong in details. Otherwise you're just asking others to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clunky regex, that kinda works. I'm not sure why it doesn't run in the StackOverflow snippet.

Here's a live example: https://lab-bhcdchzwld.now.sh

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#parse');
if (!el) return;

let regex = /http\S*/gm;
let str = el.innerHTML;

if (!str) return;

let m = regex.exec(str);
let url = m ? m[0] : null;

if (!url) return;

el.innerHTML = str.replace(url, `<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`);
```

```html
<p id="parse">this is a url https://subterrane.com/ meow</p>
```